# MSSQL - Cannot work out how to join three tables to find the building that contains people with the correct skills

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I cannot for the life of me work out a query that will take a list of Skill_ID's and return a list of Buildings that contain a person/people with all of the skills searched for

I currently have these tables

```
Building
===========
ID | name
===========
1  | BlockA
2  | BlockB


People
============================
ID |   name   |  Building_ID 
============================
1  | PersonA  |       1
2  | PersonB  |       2

Skills
===========
ID | name
===========
1  | SkillA
2  | SkillB

SkillsToPerson
====================
Person_ID | Skill_ID
====================
    1     |    1
    1     |    2 
    2     |    2
```

For example, I want to find buildings that contain at least one person with SkillA and SkillB, BlockA should be returned, because Person1 has both skills, and is in BlockA

Can anyone offer some advice? 
Thanks

Comment: Add some more sample data, and the expected result.

Comment: If the user searches for skills 1 ***and*** 2, what behaviour do you want?  If a building has a person with skill 1, but no people with skill 2, should that building be included?  What about if one person has skill 1, and another has skill 2, but no single person has both skills, should the building be returned then?  More specifics on the behaviour are required.

Comment: Note - your table naming should be more consistent, i.e. either singular or plural. I prefer singular although these days plural seems to be the norm.

Comment: @bukko Singular table names all the way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT b.Name AS Building
FROM Building b JOIN
     People p
     ON b.ID = p.Building_ID JOIN
     SkillsToPerson sp
     ON p.ID = sp.Person_ID
WHERE sp.skill_id IN (1, 2, 3)            -- Skill IDs to look for
GROUP BY b.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sp.skill_id) = 3;   -- 3 skills
```

Note that you do not need the `Skills` table because you have the skills id in `SkillsToPerson`.  Similarly, if you are happy with the building id, you don't need the building table.

I call this type of query a "set-within-sets" query, because you are looking for sets of something (skills) within another (buildings).  `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` provide a very flexible method for handling this type of query.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Building.Name
FROM People
INNER JOIN Building
ON Building.ID = People.Building_ID
INNER JOIN SkillsToPerson
ON SkillsToPerson.Person_ID = People.ID
INNER JOIN Skills
ON Skills.ID = SkillsToPerson.Skills_ID
WHERE Skills.Skill_ID IN (1, 2, 3, ...) -- list of skills here
```

Comment: That does `buildings with people with at-least one skill from the list (1,2,3,...)`, but it won't do `buildings with at-least one person that has all the skills in the list (1,2,3,...)` and it won't do `buildings with people that between them have all the skills in the list (1,2,3,...)`.  The difficulty here is that the OP isn't very clear on the actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT *
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN building b ON p.building_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN skillstoperson s ON p.id = s.person_id
LEFT JOIN skill sn ON s.skill_id = sn.id
WHERE s.skill_id = @myskill;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM BUILDING WHERE BUILDING_ID IN (SELECT BUILDING_ID FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT PERSON_ID FROM SKILLSTOPERSON WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM SKILLS WHERE SKILLNAME = 'required_skill')))
```